# why does tar . see hidden files but ls . does not?

Tags: tar

Why does `tar cvpfz /tmp/backup.tgz .` backup hidden files?

(Note `ls .` does not see the hidden files.  Trivia: there are ways to see hidden files such as with `ls -a` but this is just trivia.  The question pertains to a difference in the behaviour when similar behaviour might be expected.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick answer: use `ls -a` to see the "hidden" files.

Long story: there's no such thing as a "hidden" file in UNIX/Linux, in the sense that the Linux kernel does not mark "hidden" files in any special way (as opposed, e.g.,  to what Windows does).

There is however a *convention* that file names starting with a dot character `.` are not *displayed* by [ls](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ls) unless the user explicitly asks for it (hence, the `-a` option).  Since this was the convention adopted by the `ls` program (one of the first commands that existed in UNIX), it was followed by other file-display utilities, like Nautilus and the graphical file selection dialog.

On the other hand, since it's only a convention on displaying files, it does not affect other file-manipulating commands like `tar`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` (Short list) doesn't show hidden files.
`ll` (Long list, typically a [shell alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) to `ls -alF`) does.

Comment: Please read the question.  ll does not see hidden files.  Try it.

Comment: Yeah it does. Anyway, it does backup hidden files simply because you order it to... `man tar` or `tar --help`.

Comment: @broiyan. `ll` isn't actually a program: it's a shell alias. Exactly what it's an alias *too* may differ. Try `type ll` to see what it's aliased to on your system.